# Why the data received by HAL_UART_Receive_IT() is not correct?

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, stm32

I am trying to use STM32f407 to receive a char from Rpi4.
And I use the function-HAL_UART_Receive_IT() to receive data transmitted from Rpi4, while my Rpi4 use the function included from <wiringSerial.h>, serialPutchar().
However, when I deliver 48 in decimal ('0' in ascii code)  from Rpi4, the data received in my STM32 is 252 in decimal.
Could someone tell me how to solve it?
Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check the clock configuration of stm32. I've encountered a similar situation that I set the wrong clock frequency.

The SYSCLK should be 168 MHz, and the APB1 frequency should be 42 MHz.

Comment: I tried the clock setting you said and It can work!

Comment: By the way, Could you tell why should APB1 be 42MHZ?

Comment: Probably brr settings on uart is wrong and your uart is not working at expected baudrate. You may try keeping you previous clocks, and trasmit with the stm32 uart tx, check it with scope.

Answer (score 1):

Double check serial configuration on both sides (Polarity, bitrate, stopbit, parity... etc), if this is not enough check the trasmission with a scope and verify that what's on the line correspond to expected settings.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but I did not found differences on both sides. However, You have reminded  me what should I do if the error occurs.